# Automatically execute backup script when external hard drive is plugged with systemd

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, mount, arch-linux, systemd

I have a laptop, an external USB hard drive and a backup script.

Laptop runs Arch Linux.
External USB hard drive is encrypted with LUKS.
Backup script backups on a given mount point (/media/backup).

The current situation is that when the hard drive is plugged in, the backup script can be run manually and systemd will automatically decrypt and mount the hard drive when its mount point is accessed. This is achieved with the following:

`/etc/crypttab`:

`backupdrive     UUID=xxxyyy-1234-4567-8910-aaabbb       /path/to/luks-backup-hdd-keyfile    luks,noauto`

`/etc/fstab`:

`/dev/mapper/backupdrive /media/backup   ext4    noauto,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=5s,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min       0  2`

This is working fine. I would like to improve this by executing the backup script automatically when this specific device is detected by systemd.

This is where I am not sure to understand but I guess the mount should happen automatically when the device is plugged, not waiting for the mount point to be accessed. And then the backup script should be a systemd service that should be triggered by the mount but I'm not sure how (with `wants` maybe?).

Ideally I would like to achieve this directly with native systemd units rather than using fstab.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess the mount should happen automatically when the device is plugged, not waiting for the mount point to be accessed.

Then don't use `x-systemd.automount`.

Previously, what you describe used to happen with just the regular `auto` option, but this was removed because many people didn't expect `auto` to take effect after boot has finished.

With current systemd versions, you'll need to manually add a `Wants=media-backup.mount` dependency to the disk. Each device has a virtual `.device` unit, and while those units themselves don't exist on disk, they still accept additional configuration (drop-ins, etc) the same way.

I *think* this should work:

```
device_unit=$(systemd-escape -p /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxyyy-1234-4567-8910-aaabbb).device
mount_unit=$(systemd-escape -p /media/backup).mount

systemctl add-wants "$device_unit" media-backup.mount
```

If that doesn't work, it's also doable through udev (e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-automount.rules`):

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="xxxyyy-1234-4567-8910-aaabbb", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="media-backup.mount"
```

> And then the backup script should be a systemd service that should be triggered by the mount but I'm not sure how (with wants maybe?).

Yes, add your service as a *Wants=* into media-backup.mount.

In your case media-backup.mount is automatically built from the fstab entry, so you cannot edit the whole .mount unit directly, but you *can* add dependencies to it similar to the above example:

```
systemctl add-wants media-backup.mount my-backup-script.service
```

Comment: I like the idea of `add-wants` a mount to a device unit, I didn't know that. But no matter how I try to tell `add-wants` about the device unit, it always replies that device unit does not exist. I tried it with `systemd-escape` as described, and even with just the path to `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx` it seems the escape is done automatically as it is written in the right format in the error message. And when I list the units I can clearly see the device units of that HDD being present. I guess I'll have to resort to udev.

Comment: The udev rule worked immediately to mount the fs on HDD plug. That's fine, but I will keep trying to use only systemd as I find it cleaner to not have to fiddle with different tools.

Comment: If `systemctl add-wants` didn't work, try manually creating the symlink in `/etc/systemd/system/dev-…-xxx.device.wants/`.

Comment: yes, I like that approach and was willing to do it. But, the mount unit is virtual since it is created from fstab. And so I don't know where I should link on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the kernel log or system log for capture the event of plugging the external HDD. After that, you can look for a perticuler string in the log file and perform any actions when string appears like this.

```
 tail -F /var/log/syslog | grep --line-buffered 'Connected to wireless network' | while read ; do echo "Wifi Connected" ; done
```